# Javascript while loop conditions

Tags: javascript

The following javascript fragment goes into an infinite loop. Why is that?

```
 var playerChoice=prompt("Choose paper or rock or scissors"); 
 while (playerChoice !=="paper" || playerChoice !=="rock" || playerChoice !== "scissors"){   
       playerChoice=prompt("Choose paper or rock or scissors"); 
 }
```

Comment: it should just be ```playerChoice != "paper"```

Comment: why are you not usin if condition??

Comment: tried it with != still not working!!!

Comment: @Minhajraz `!=` vs `!==` shouldn't make a difference here.  Have you tried switching to using `&&` instead of `||` as per the various answers?

Answer (score 4):

Because when a new choice is made, it will always match at least two of the conditions, and since you've used the [OR (`||`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR), will continue with the loop.  You need to use the [AND (`&&`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND) instead:

```
var playerChoice=prompt("Choose paper or rock or scissors");

while (playerChoice !=="paper" && playerChoice !=="rock" && playerChoice !== "scissors"){
    playerChoice=prompt("Choose paper or rock or scissors"); 
}
```

Now when a valid choice is made, two of the 3 inner conditions are still met, but because the last one isn't, the whole condition will evaluate to `false` and the loop will not execute.

Comment: Thanks for explanations @james Thorpe.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `&&`. You need to quit the loop if the choice is either one of the valid choices

```
while (playerChoice != "paper" && playerChoice != "rock" && playerChoice != "scissors") {
    playerChoice = prompt("Choose paper or rock or scissors");
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/p8tp1L0d/)

In your case assume, `playerChoice` is `paper` but when evaluating your condition `playerChoice !=="rock"` is true and since you have used `||` if any of the condition is true the loop will get executed

Comment: The issue is with the ```!=```, is it not?

Comment: I thought && will only return 'true' if all the values are true. I want it to return  true if either case is true

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald See the Strict Inequality operator vs the Inequality operator.  `!==` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald: No, it isn't.

Comment: Any one with any other idea?? I am stack here!

Comment: @Minhajraz check the attached fiddle seems to be working

Answer (score 0):

You're using OR where you should be using AND, whether Rock, Paper or Scissors is entered two of your conditions will evaluate as TRUE so you'll go around the loop again, and again, and again.....